# jQuery lightbox(featherlight) how to run beforeOpen and afterOpen event

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, featherlight.js

I am working with this jQuery lightbox which is [featherlight](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight) and don't understand how to fire bellow events as I am not good so I am hopping someones help:

**Before Open:**

```
beforeOpen: function(event){

}
```

**After Open:**

```
afterOpen: function(event){

}
```

**My Code Work:**

```
<button id="openbox" href="#fl1">Load Lightbox on click event</button>

<div class="lightbox" id="fl1">
    <h2>Delete Item</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <strong>Are you Sure?</strong>
            <br>blubblub?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right"> <a href="#" class="btn btn_gray no text_none" id="close_button">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn_red text_none">Yes</a>
    </div>
</div>


$('#openbox').click(function() {
    $.featherlight('#fl1');
});
```

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g68bZ/29/

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have downloaded the source code and follows the documents and both event are working properly with your example.

**HTML Part:**

```
<button id="openbox" href="#fl1">Load Lightbox on click event</button>
<div class="lightbox" id="fl1">
    <h2>Delete Item</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <strong>Are you Sure?</strong>
            <br>blubblub?
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right"> <a href="#" class="btn btn_gray no text_none" id="close_button">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn_red text_none">Yes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Part:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
    window.onload=function(){
        $('button.#openbox').featherlight({
            targetAttr: 'href',
            beforeOpen: function(event){
                alert('beforeOpen');
            },
            afterOpen: function(event){
                alert('afterOpen');
            }
        });
    }           
</script>
```

Check this running [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mananpatel/LLq4b6mh/)

Let me know If you need any other help.

Comment: late comment; in 2016, on FF, the jsfiddle doesn't open the lightbox

Comment: As @OwenBeresford noted, the jsfiddle stopped working at some point. It was due to the links to the external files dying in the interim. I've put up a quick-and-dirty update here: http://jsfiddle.net/bookchiq/LejLwnq9/4/

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you can use the following:

```
$('.myElement').featherlight($content, configuration);
```

$content being a jQuery object, and configuration being an object:

In your example:

```
var configuration = ({
   afterOpen: function(event){
      //code here
   },
   beforeOpen: function(event){
     //code here
   }
});

$('#openbox').click(function() {
    $.featherlight('#fl1', configuration);
});
```

I haven't tested it, but this should help you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi. Can you please provide me with fiddle. Thanks.

Comment: From looking at the docs & the source code, I get a feeling it might not be working at all.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the plugin, my code is per their documentation. I think that plugin might not yet be fully functional.